# i have a website running on port 8080 and i want to install nodejs on port 8000 to send push notifications. but it is not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have hosted a website on hostgator. Now i want to send push notifications to android default browser from my server. I figured out that socket io running on nodejs is the perfect solution for that. 
I have done some hands-on and have run nodejs on my server. I am able to get the response using that.

My issue is that I am not able to connect to nodejs server from the page running on my website. Please help me with it

appjs

`var app = require('http').createServer(handler)`
`, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)`
 `, fs = require('fs')`

`app.listen(1050);`

`function handler (req, res) {`
`fs.readFile( './index.php',`
`function (err, data) {`
   `if (err) {`
    `res.writeHead(500);`
     `return res.end('Error loading index.html');`
    `}`

```
`res.writeHead(200);`
```

`res.end(data +"sever");`
  `});`
`}`

`io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {`
`//res.write("server");`
 `socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });`
  `socket.on('my other event', function (data) {`
   `console.log(data);`
  `});`
 `//socket.emit('mynewevent', {'demo'});`
`});`
`

index,php

`<?php`
        `require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php");`
        `require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");`
        `include("Includes/header.php");`
     `?>`

```
  `  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
  `  <script type="text/javascript">``



     `   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1050');`
      `  socket.on('news', function (data) {`
      `  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'serverrrrrrrrrrr' });`

       ` });`

        `socket.on('mynewevent', function (data) {`
        `alert(data);`
       ` });`
```

`</script>`
 `<div id="main">`
  `<h3>Get started with your website</h3>`

   
      
         Login as admin 
       The site admin username and password are stored in the config file in directory
       
      
         Customize your site
         After you login, you can add, delete, and modify web pages.
    
  
     
        To learn more about PHP, visit `Website">http://php.net</a>.
 `</div>`
  `</li>`
   `</ol>`

```
`</div>`
```

`</div> <!-- End of outer-wrapper which opens in header.php -->`

`<?php`
 `include ("Includes/footer.php");`
 `?>`
``

Solution

Solved by replacing the 
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

with

```
<script src="http://localhost:1050/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you have port 8000 open to the Internet.  It's likely firewalled off.

Comment: Done that. Its already opened. Have tried changing port number as well.